# How to use unittest setUp method only once to set attributes used in test submodules?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to have a unittest Class that instantiate a Class once and sets this instance in an attribute that can be reusable in tests submodules (NOT other tests in this file).

```
e.g: 
\tests
   test_main.py
   \subtests_1
       test_1.py
   \subtests_2
       test_2.py
```

In the test_main.py:

```
class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        config = Config('test')
```

In the test_1.py and test_2.py I want to access this attribute without (re)instantiating my config.

```
class TestHello(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def SetUp(self):
        my_object = MyObject(self.config)
```

The reason why is because all classes that I want to test needs to be instantiated be this config so I would like to avoid redundancy.

I tested it in the **init**.py or in the test_main.py file and I'm sure that unittest pass through this method but I can't access it in submodules even with the setUpClass method. Maybe I don't access it in a right way.

I tried accessing it with

```
self.__class__.config 
self.config
```

Each time I have the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'TestHello' has no attribute 'config'
```

Any advise would be very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Tests are expected to be independant and you should never rely on one installing something for a different one. But Python unittest module provide 3 *setUp* (and *tearDown*) levels:

- the *normal* test level: the `setUp` (and `tearDown`) methods are called for each test method.
- the *class* level: the classmethods `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` are called only once for the whole class before (and after) all test methods of the class are executed.
- the *module* level: a test module can also contain the free functions `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule`. They are called (resp.) before any test in the module and after all have been executed.

They can be used to perform only once expensive initialization, or initialize objects that have to be shared among several tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's exactly what I was looking for !